# Listing first name, last name at Users listing page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have installed and configured User Profile module, which allows me to add fields like First Name, Last Name for users.

As of now, when I go to users list at /admin/user/user I see username column. How can I can add these extra fields in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create a view that replaces the content of the page on /admin/user/user.
The module, which requires [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), define a view visible on admin/user/user2 that duplicates the content of the page /admin/user/user.